# Not work get geolocation in webview on Android 11

Tags: android, webview, geolocation

What am I wrong about? This code works on Android 7..10, but does not work in Android 11. HTML gives an access error

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  " />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In webview interception on geolocation request:

```
        mbrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mycontext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED |
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mycontext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED|
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mycontext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);{
                AddToLog("Вывожу запрос на доступ к GPS если надо..");
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 100);
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 101);
                checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS, 102);
            };
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
```

In HTML:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
function(location) {
    latitude=location.coords.latitude;
    longitude=location.coords.longitude;
    accuracy=location.coords.accuracy; 
    console.log("- WORK!")
  },
    function(error){
        console.log("- NOT WORK!")
   },{enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout: 2000,
         maximumAge: 60000}
 );
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

please use this permission only for android 10 and above

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an error in Javascript. In Android 11, in webview, the method "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" not work. The universal solution for Android 7..11 is the following:

```
     function fetchLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError)
    } else {            
        console.log("- without transmitting geolocation ((")            
    }
 }
function onGeoSuccess(event){
    latitude=event.coords.latitude;
    longitude=event.coords.longitude;
    accuracy=event.coords.accuracy; //точность
    console.log("- you can shoot coordinates in the browser method #2")
    geosupport=true;
}
function onGeoError(event){
        console.log("-  without transmitting geolocation ((")
}

    console.log("--test method 1");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(location) {
        latitude=location.coords.latitude;
        longitude=location.coords.longitude;
        accuracy=location.coords.accuracy; //точность
        console.log("- you can shoot coordinates in the browser method #2")
      },
        function(error){
            console.log("-test method 2");
            fetchLocation();
       },{enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout: 2000,
                         maximumAge: 60000}
  );
```